# check existance of every value in IN statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a query like below. What i want is to select null or blank if there is no records for a particular value in the IN statement.
There values are entered by user.

```
select system_code, max(last_update_timestamp) as [last_update_timestamp]
from table_name
where system_code in ('E1','E2','E3')
Group by system_code

E1 has 100 records
E2 has 20 records
E3 has no records
```

Using the above query i am getting this result :

```
Sytem_code      last_update_timestamp
E1              '2014-09-28 11:35:10.647' 
E2              '2014-09-28 11:35:10.647'
```

Expected reuslt

```
Sytem_code      last_update_timestamp
E1              '2014-09-28 11:35:10.647' 
E2              '2014-09-28 11:35:10.647' 
E3               Null or Blank
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Table Value Constructor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd776382.aspx) to build an in-line table containing all values of the `IN` operator. Then `LEFT JOIN` your query to this table:

```
SELECT x.sc, [last_update_timestamp]
FROM (VALUES ('E1'), ('E2'), ('E3')) AS x(sc)
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT system_code, max(last_update_timestamp) as [last_update_timestamp]
   FROM table_name 
   WHERE system_code IN ('E1','E2','E3')
   GROUP BY system_code ) AS t ON x.sc = t.system_code
```

[**Demo here**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e6886/1)

Comment: @TimSchmelter Yes, sure. The reader can easily deduce this if he/she clicks on *Other versions* on the msdn page my answer references to.

Comment: No need to open the link and click on "other versions" since i've mentioned it already. I thought it's worth noting because OP hasn't mentioned his version. (I'm still on 2005 so this doesn't work for me f.e.)

Answer (score 1):

That query works for most DB engines

```
select tmp.system_code, max(table_name.last_update_timestamp) as [last_update_timestamp]
from 
(
  select 'E1' as system_code 
  union all
  select 'E2'
  union all
  select 'E3'
) tmp
left join table_name on tmp.system_code = table_name.system_code 
                    and table_name.system_code in ('E1','E2','E3')
Group by tmp.system_code
```

Comment: I think and table_name.system_code in ('E1','E2','E3') is redundant

Comment: "works for all DB engines" No it doesn't. Maybe all versions of SQL Server, but Oracle requires a from clause for all selects and has a special table, DUAL, for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.sc, max(last_update_timestamp) as [last_update_timestamp]
  FROM (VALUES ('E1'), ('E2'), ('E3')) AS x(sc)
  LEFT JOIN table_name 
         ON table_name.system_code = x.sc
 GROUP BY x.sc
```